# How to make a tabHost in an Activity that is not a TabActivity

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabhost

I made a tabHost in an Activty and everytime it reaches the .addTab(Spec) it crashes.
I created the tab host in the Activity like so:

```
peopleTabHost = new TabHost(this);
```

and then I use a method to add the tab (I can do that because I defined the peopleTabHost as final outside of the onCreat)

```
    private void CreateNewTab(String tagName, String displayedName, Class<?> intentClass)
    {
          Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this,  intentClass);
          TabHost.TabSpec spec = peopleTabHost.newTabSpec(tagName).setIndicator(displayedName);
          spec.setContent(intent);
          peopleTabHost.addTab(spec);       
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second sianis' answer, but I'm also adding that it might be crashing because you are not initializing (or at least not showing) the tabhost.

Try to run `peopleTabHost.setup();` right after calling the constructor.

Comment: Ok thank you, I extend TabActivity, and it works. now I have a different problem, the class that contain the tabs also contain a list that supposed to be below the tabs and each one of them fills half the screen. I did that by adding both of them into a vertical linear layout, but it crashes, and by the debugger it hapens when it gets to the addView of the tab host.

Comment: You probably should open up a different thread with your code and your stack trace to provide means for more people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use TabActivity? It is a class which extends ActivityGroup which extends Activity. So you can use a child of TabActivity class like a simple Activity, but it has some more functionality.